# VSCode python debugger crashes

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I have a new clean installation of VSCode on Linux Mint 18.2. I've installed Python 0.8.0, Python Extension Pack 1.0.1, Python for VSCode 0.2.3 and MagicPython 1.0.12

I can debug code in the integrated console but not in an external console. Since I'm writing code that must be run as a super user, that means I can't debug the code (the integrated terminal will not run sudo code).

When I try and debug, the debug console throws 'Error: spawn ENODIR'. The launch.json section is as follows:

```
        "name": "Python: Terminal (external)",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "stopOnEntry": true,
        "pythonPath": "/usr/bin/python3.5m",
        "program": "${file}",
        "cwd": "/home/jsb/development/diskHealth/health.py",
        "console": "externalTerminal",
        "env": {},
        "envFile": "${workspaceRoot}/.env",
        "debugOptions": [
            "WaitOnAbnormalExit",
            "WaitOnNormalExit",
            "Sudo"
        ]
```

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: Do note you have competing extensions installed, so in order to help provide any guidance you will need to be running only a single Python extension to know which one is acting as the debugger.

Comment: Thanks - I've uninstalled everything except Microsoft Python 0.8.0. I now get the error 'Debug adapter process has terminated unexpectedly'

Comment: You're probably bumping up against https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/71 .

Comment: It turns out that the new version of VSCode fixes the problem - whatever it was. Thanks for the help